# Query on String Rotation program using concatenation. Why doesn't it work fully?

Tags: c, string

I had written a code for string rotation using C. In the code given below, I copied the original string onto another variable and made use of the strncat function to get a section of the original string which is rotated to the end. And then I declared another string variable and copied the character of the concatenated string which we required to get the result.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void stringrotation(char *a,int rot)
{
    char s[10];
    char r[10]="";
    strcpy(s,a);
    strncat(s,a,rot);
    printf("%s\n",s);
    for(int i=rot; i<strlen(s);++i)
    {
        r[i-rot]=s[i];
    }
    printf("%s",r);
}

int main()
{
    char *r="abcedef";
    int rot=2;
    stringrotation(r,rot);
}
```

This code works only for values of variable rot= 1,2 and 3. I want to know why doesn't work for the rest of the values? Could anyone provide a code with the similar technique used, but versatile for all strings

Comment: calling `strlen(s)` in the loop condition is not the most efficient pattern

Comment: what is the expected output? "cdef" or "cdefab"? do you want this operation to be in-place?

Comment: The expected output is "cdefab", Also I will remove the strlen(s) from the loop condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple errors in your code. The potential *stack overflow* if `strlen(a) > 10` is one example. Moreover, it does not produce a right output because character in `rot` after `strlen(a)-rot` are not correct.

Generally, string interfaces in C return a string as return value.
It lets a cascade of calls `strfun1(strfun2(strfun3(...` work.
Additionally, the user can decide what to do with the value, i.e. how the value will be presented.

Moreover, it is a good idea to let a user provide destination buffer to speedup operation and reduce memory consumption.

Passing `NULL` as destination can be use to ask the function to allocate a suitable buffer. Remember to free it with `free()` when buffer is no longer used to avoid leakage.

If possible, use `memcpy()` functions as those tend to be more optimized.

The final code could be:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *stringrotation(const char *src, int rot, char *dst) {
    size_t len = strlen(src);

    // make sure that rotation makes sense
    if (rot < 0 || rot >= len) return NULL;

    // if no storade for output is provided, allocate it
    if (dst == NULL) {
        // allocated but for `len` characters and a terminator
        dst = malloc(len + 1);
        // check if allocation succeeded
        if (!dst) return NULL;
    }

    // copy tail of the input to the output
    memcpy(dst, src + rot, len - rot);
    // concat head of the input to the output
    memcpy(dst + len - rot, src, rot);
    // add terminator to output
    dst[len] = 0;

    return dst;
}

int main()
{
    char a[10];
    stringrotation("abcdef", 2, a);
    puts(a);

    // reverse the first operation
    char *b = stringrotation(a, 4, NULL);
    puts(b);
    free(b);

    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
cdefab
abcdef
```

Answer (score 0):

You just don't have enough space to copy string. `s[20]` will help you.
If it's code for c++ it's better to use `std::string` or `std::vector`.
P.S. If you want I can provide variant with `std::string`

Comment: Thanks for the solution Anatolii. You were right about the lack of space.